# Error referencing header file to create an application to reference dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, header

I have been trying to follow the walkthrough for Microsoft Visual Studio, Walkthrough: [Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), as I am a beginner.

However, I keep getting errors that I am having difficulty understanding and solving.

First of all it kept saying that there was an error:

> warning C4627: '#include ': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
>   1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header

So I did some online searching and it appeared that I should add in the line:

> #include "StdAfx.h"

into the .cpp file, MyExecRefsDll.cpp, which I did, at the top of the code.

It then came up with the error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'MathFuncsDll.h': No such file or directory

I have included a reference for this header file, which is the header file I actually want to use. I can see this reference under:
MyExecRefsDll property pages\configuration properties\c/c++\General, then next to Additional Include directories I have, C:..etc..\DynamicLibrary\MathFuncsDll\MathFuncsDll.h

I read about turning off using precompiled headers. Is this what I need to do, but I am not sure how?

I also read something about using .lib instead of .dll for referencing the dynamic link library. I tried this, changing the reference for the dll under:
MyExecRefsDll property pages\configuration properties\Debugging, next to Environment I have typed, PATH=C:\Users...etc...\DynamicLibrary\Debug\MathFuncsDll.dll 
I tried to change the end of the file name to .lib instead, but nothing changed, the error was still at the problem with finding the MathFuncsDll.h file.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the header file to work so I can build the solution successfully? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are just not following the instructions in the walkthrough accurately.  Do it again.

Comment: I did follow the walkthrough as accurately as I could, twice. If I am missing something, then I must have mis-understood what I am supposed to type, and hence the errors, and hence I do not understand where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Yes I agree with @HansPassant, 'hde' has not followed the exact steps, also there is no need to change environment PATH variable. Follow the exact steps of MSDN tutorial and it works. Make sure you are configuring correct build type : Debug/Release. Better to configure both!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio only presents that error if it is unable to find the header file. In order to solve that you should check you project settings. In your question you refer that "I have, C:..etc..\DynamicLibrary\MathFuncsDll\MathFuncsDll.h", where in the Additional Include directories you should have only the name of the directory, like "C:..etc..\DynamicLibrary\MathFuncsDll\".
Check that the file is really there and also double-check that you are editing the project settings related to your current build configuration, i.e. if you are building Debug|Win32, you should change the Additional Include Directories there.

Comment: I had Active Release build and I modified debug type of build. Hence I was getting error for include directories. Worked for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I believe that there is a bug in VisualStudio 10.

Here is the troublesome step from the walkthrough:

> To reference the header files of the dynamic link library, you must
>   modify the include directories path. To do this, from the Property
>   Pages dialog, expand the Configuration Properties node, then the C/C++
>   node, and select General. Next to Additional Include Directories, type
>   in the path to the location of the MathFuncsDll.h header file.

Here Visual Studio will give you a "Browse" button so that you can navigate to the desired directory and select it. Doing this will insert the entire path into the `Additional Include Directories`.

However, this still does not work for me.

The only way I could get it to compile was to type in the relative path:

..\..\MathFuncsDll\MathFuncsDll\

Answer (score -1):

There is a very simple solution to this problem.

In Visual Studio 2010 under

```
Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Precompiled Headers
```

Set the value for the "Precompiled Header" attribute to "Not Using Precompiled Headers," follow the instructions as listed, and the demo should build without error.